# code for fetching an email from the Gmail inbox

Tags: email, php4

I am trying to develop a program for fetching email from  the inbox of gmail. Can you help me for doing... If the code can automatically fetch the email, it is very good.. I am preferring
php code.....

Answer (score 1):

Yes saif, use IMAP extension in php to garb email 
See the link below for php code.

http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Thank you

Comment: can you give that full code for me....That code getting imp_open() cannot do..... how i can correct that error. more than all really thanks for giving this idea.... thanks sir

Comment: Saif, I think it may be Firewall issue, localhost brings some trouble. Try it in live server or change firewall setting.
Thank you

Comment: thanks sir now i corrected that one.. but actually i need to take the link address which are being in the email body. Can you Please help me for doing that .

Comment: only the link address? specified in the mail body

Comment: Take the subject value from the mail and use preg match to retrieve all the email values

Comment: i tried foe that but it is not working. i want to get the link contained in the message body .. only that one needed. how we can search for that.. can we think it should be in the form of http://www.orkut.com' .. how we can take that and browse the address in different tab automatically... you said a good idea first.. thanks for helping me.....

Answer (score 0):

Gmail allows for the use of IMAP, so if you can write an IMAP client, you can connect and grab mail from GMail.